# particular solution of non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we assume $A e^{-t}$ (method of undetermined coefficient)to be a particular solution of $y'' - 3y' - 4y = 2e^{-t}$, we can't find the $A$. The book says to try with $Ate^{-t}$. I am trying to understand this. Please suggest.

Comment: Let $L(y)=ay''+by'+cy$, then, in full generality, if $y(t)=w(t)e^{\lambda t}$ for some polynomial $z$ of degree $n$ then $L(y)(t)=K(w)(t)e^{\lambda t}$ where $K(w)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$. When $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, that is, $a\lambda^2+b\lambda+c=0$, then "degree at most $n$" can be replaced by "degree at most $n-d+1$" where $d$ denotes the order of the root $\lambda$. Thus, to solve $L(y)(t)=z(t)e^{\lambda t}$ for some polynomial $z$ of degree $n$ one looks for $y(t)=w(t)e^{\lambda t}$ where $w$ is a polynomial of degree $n+d-1$. Here, ...

Comment: ... $z(t)=2$ hence $n=0$ and $\lambda=-1$ yields $d=2$ thus one looks for $w$ of degree $0+2-1=1$.

Comment: You might look at http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/coco/coco.html and http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/undcoef/undcoef.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the characteristic eq is
$$ r^2-3r-4=0 $$
which has two roots $r_1=-1,r_2=4$. If $y=Ae^{-t}$, you can not determine $A$ since the coefficient of the power $-t$ in $y=Ae^{-t}$ is $-1$ which is the same as $r_1=-1$. So you have to use $y=Ate^{-t}$ to seek a particular solution.

Comment: thanks. But why multiply $t$ and not any other function?

Comment: @user55531, think this: you want to seek a particular solution $y=Ae^{rt}$ but you can not get. Then differentiating $Ae^{rt}$ w.r.t you will get $Ate^{rt}$. That's the reason there is $t$.